# I am not able to launch tensorboard in the browser(safari and chrome)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have my event_file as follow:

```
/path/to/event_file/events.out.tfevents.1516382034.myremotehost.edu
```

Then I try to launch tensorbord using this command:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/event_file --port=6006
```

and it gives me the following URL:

```
http://myremotehost.edu:6006
```

but obviously looking at the result of

```
 netstat -l / -a / -t / -u / -n
```

port 6006 is not open, so I tried to redirect the port 6006 on localhost using:

```
ssh -L 6006:localhost:6006 myremotehost.edu -N
```

looking at the result of the netstat, it says port 6006 is listening. Then I try to launch tensorboard again using:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/event_file --port=6006
```

It says:

```
TensorBoard attempted to bind to port 6006, but it was already in use
```

am I doing something wrong? I will appreciate any help.
I also tried:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/event_file --host=localhost --port=6006
```

and also:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/event_file --host=myremotehost.edu --port=6006
```

no success. I also tried different port number, no success either.

Edit:

It doesn't let me to answer my own question, so I post it as an edit:

The problem in my case was, I first ssh to myremotehost using this:

```
ssh -L localhost:44888:localhost:55888 myusername@myremotehost.edu
```

and the inside that terminal was trying to launch tensorboard using this:

tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/event_file --host=myremotehost.edu --port=6006

Obviously didn't work. The solution is, I don't need to ssh to myremorehost in a regular way, instead I need to do this:

```
1)   ssh -L localhost:4040:localhost:6006

2)   ssh -D 8080 myusername@myremotehost.edu

3)   go to the network setting in your browser and change the proxy setting as below:
```

[Network Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okf6b.png)

This works for both Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 16. Safari loads the tensordboard page, but I can't see the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Safari you don't need to enter this:
http://myremotehost.edu:6006

Instead, after launching the tensorboard --logdir=path/to/logdir
Just put this in your Safari browser
http://localhost:6006